# Sonarlint reporting "Undefined function" for defined functions in PHP in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I am using SonfarLint in VS Code and it is reporting "Undefined function" for every function which is not declared in the current file (i.e in an include or require file).

When I click on the call, VS Code takes me to the function declaration. The code runs correctly. It's just that SonarLint doesn't see it. I can't believe that it doesn't parse include/require files.

Maybe it's just a configuration thing?

---

[Update] Perhaps it's the syntax that I use to `require` files?

E.g  `require_once __DIR__ .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'constants.php';`

But, surely, SonarLint can parse that?

Comment: Why not report this on their site? https://community.sonarsource.com/ Someone there may actually be an expert